# How to change this into a preprocessor macro

Tags: c, cuda, c-preprocessor

I have this statement and I want to change this in the form of a macro:

```
int *arr; <br>
int T;
cudaMalloc( &arr, sizeof(int) * (1+T) );
```

I did something like this but this is not working in program.

```
#define fun(a,b,c) cudaMalloc( (a), sizeof( b) * (1+ c));
```

How this could be done?

Comment: How did you invoke that macro?

Comment: That `;` at the end should probably be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
#define CUDA_MALLOC(a, b, c) (cudaMalloc( (a), sizeof(b) * (1 + (c)) ))
// other code
cuda_ret = CUDA_MALLOC(&arr, float, no_elements);
```

Note the lack of a semicolon at the end of the line and the extra parentheses to guard against problems resulting from operator precedence.

On a side note, I'm not convinced using these kinds of macros is a good practice.